# Cannot connect to mySQL after recovering InnoDB tables without Ibdata1 file [xampp and localhost]

Tags: xampp, mariadb, innodb

First of all, you should know that I have few knowledge of mySQL, databases, xampp and so on. I will try to explain my problem the best I can.

Secondly, notice that I have already searched for solutions in this site and others, but I do not find anyone that applies to my specific situation.

I was developing my first wordpress website using bitnami_wordpress and xampp. A few days ago I had a problem connecting to a mySQL local server. Due to my ignorance, when I was trying to solve my problem, I ended up overwriting the ibdata1 file from my xampp/mysql/data folder with the one stored in xampp\mysql\backup. Big mistake! The backup may be too old and now my database was "corrupted". When I tried to access the tables in the phpmyadmin panel there was a message saying "table doesn't exist in engine".

I looked for solutions in the net and I finally decided to follow these steps to restore my data: https://zadpen.com/20-restore-lost-data-in-mysql-using-innodb-engine-without-file-ibdata1.html

These are the main steps:

1. Add `innodb_file_per_table=1` in xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini
2. Create a new database for the website (I used same name as the original one while I changed the name of the old one)
3. Recovering the tables structure of the old database. For example: `mysqlfrm --server=root:@localhost:3306 wp_cn_social_icon.frm --port 3333 > wp_cn_social_icon.sql`
4. Creating the table using the SQL statements of the previous step.
5. Discard the .ibd files of the new database `ALTER TABLE wp_cn_social_icon DISCARD TABLESPACE;`
6. Copying the original .ibd file from the old database to the new one.
7. "linking" the .ibd to the .frm file of the new database: `ALTER TABLE wp_cn_social_icon IMPORT TABLESPACE;`

I repeated these steps for all the tables.

It worked. I was able to see again all the data in the tables in the phpmyadmin control panel! I was so happy! HOWEVER, happiness lasted a few minutes. As soon as I stopped Xampp and restarted it again, I found up that I was able to access other databases in the phpMyAdmin panel, but not the website database I was interested in. This was the error:

[image: Connection_error]

I think nothing is wrong in the configInc.php file...is it?

```
/* Authentication type and info */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = true;
$cfg['Lang'] = '';

/* Bind to the localhost ipv4 address and tcp */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1:3306';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
```

I then tried to connect to the server through the Windows CMD (I didnt' know what to do... I was just desperate) I used the command: `mysql -u root -p`. And then I write down: `mysql use website_database`. After doing this, the connection was interrupted and I have not been able to start again the mysql server.

Now Xampp shows this error everytime I attempt to start MySQL.

```
16:45:33  [mysql]   Attempting to start MySQL app...
16:45:33  [mysql]   Status change detected: running
16:45:36  [mysql]   Status change detected: stopped
16:45:36  [mysql]   Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
16:45:36  [mysql]   This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
16:45:36  [mysql]   improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
16:45:36  [mysql]   Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
16:45:36  [mysql]   the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
16:45:36  [mysql]   If you need more help, copy and post this                        
16:45:36  [mysql]   entire log window on the forums
```

The mysql_error.log file shows this:

```
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 16M, instances = 1, chunk size = 16M
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file 'C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: File 'C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\data\ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.11 started; log sequence number 896271; transaction id 990
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from C:\Program Files\xampp\mysql\data\ib_buffer_pool
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2020-06-06 16:45:34 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

I did not change any connection settings... I Just followed the steps of that website to recover the data. What may be wrong? I must be doing something wrong or missing something related with the connecting settings.

PS: Just in case, I found strange that Ibdata1 file weighs now almost 70Mb...

Comment: `ibdata1` is _vital_ to the functioning of InnoDB, even with `innodb_file_per_table = ON`.  If you have no backup, you are SOL.

Comment: oh!! I though it was possible... Then this [website](https://www.nullalo.com/en/recover-mysql-innodb-tables-without-ibdata1-file/) is wrong?

Comment: Keep searching.  If you have the `CREATE TABLE`, it may be possible to use that to provide the basis, then somehow hook the data (in the .ibd) to the newly created table.

Comment: **10.4.11** is a MariaDB version number, not a MySQL version number. XAMPP bundles MariaDB, not MySQL. I've changed the tags for this question.